# Почему может не срабатывать ng-click в angular v.1.3?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-controller, angular-routing

Пробовал разными методами привязать к событию функцию, но кажется событие не отрабатывает даже в банальных примерах. Возможно глупый вопрос, помогите разобраться

```
<a href="" ng-click="console.log('test')">
```

или так:

```
<a href="" ng-click="UserController.update(user)">
```

В файле контроллера пишу это:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$sce', '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', '$cookieStore', 'UserService', UserController]);

function UserController($scope, $sce, $window, $location, $rootScope, $cookieStore, UserService) {
    var self = this;

    // VARS  //
    self.users = [];
    self.update = update;

    function update(user) {
        return 'test';
    }
   }
 })();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это все из-за того, что **все**, что пишется во view, берется из `$scope`.

Так как в скопе контроллера нет ни свойства `console`, ни свойства `UserController` - ангуляр тихо проглатывает ошибку и ничего не выводит.

Для того чтобы заработал `console`, в контроллере нужно добавить его в скоп, например так:

```
$scope.console = console;
```

---

Для того, чтобы заработал вариант с контроллером - нужно использовать `controllerAs`

```
ng-controller="UserController as UserController"
```

При этом, в скоп добавляется поле с именем UserController ссылающееся на текущий экземпляр контроллера.

Эта запись эквивалентна следующей в коде:

```
$scope.UserController = this;
```

---

Примеры:

С установкой в коде:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('UserController', ['$scope', UserController]);

  function UserController($scope) {
    var self = this;

    // VARS  //
    self.users = [];
    self.update = update;

    $scope.console = console;
    $scope.UserController = this;

    function update(user) {
      console.log('update->test');
      return 'test';
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="UserController">
    <a href="" ng-click="console.log('test')">Console.log('test')</a>
    <br/>

    <a href="" ng-click="UserController.update(user)">UserController.update(user)</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

С `controllerAs` синтаксисом

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('UserController', ['$scope', UserController]);

  function UserController($scope) {
    var self = this;

    // VARS  //
    self.users = [];
    self.update = update;

    $scope.console = console;

    function update(user) {
      console.log('update->test');
      return 'test';
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="UserController as UserController">
    <a href="" ng-click="console.log('test')">Console.log('test')</a>
    <br/>

    <a href="" ng-click="UserController.update(user)">UserController.update(user)</a>
  </div>
</div>
```